# How to create a reusable type for a decorator which does not alter the signature of its input function

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

I am trying to create a type which represents a specific kind of decorator. This decorator will take a function with any signature and return a function with the same signature.

This is what I came up with:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Callable, Any

Func = TypeVar('Func', bound=Callable[..., Any])


def decorator(f: Func) -> Func:
    return f


d: Callable[[Func], Func] = decorator
```

This works fine, but I would like to extract the `Callable[[Func], Func]` into a variable so that I could easily reuse it for other decorators:

```py
Decorator = Callable[[Func], Func] 

d: Decorator = decorator
```

Unfortunately, when I run `mypy --strict` I get this error:

`error: Missing type parameters for generic type "Decorator"  [type-arg]`

Is there any way I can implement this `Decorator` type without getting errors from `mypy`?

Comment: It's a bug, check [this issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/13449) which is very similar to your use case.

Comment: Did you trying creating the Decorator using Type? `Decorator = Type[Callable[[Func], Func]]`

Comment: @JamiuShaibu it's simply wrong...

Comment: What about ```Func2 = Callable[..., Any];
Decorator2 = Callable[[Func2], Func2];
d2: Decorator2 = decorator```?

Comment: @relent95 this just kills the type checking, resulting function is inferred as `(*args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Any` if you throw type variable away.